# How can I use action for category filter in dropdown list in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Categories

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
    @foreach (var category in _category)
    {
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Site" asp-action="CategotyFilter" asp-route-id="@category.Id">@category.Name</a>

    }

</div>
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CategotyFilter(int Id)
{

 var filteredBooks = await _appDbContext.VwBooks.Where(b=>b.CategoryId.Equals(Id)).OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).ToListAsync();

 return View(filteredBooks);

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.